# Interacting with Windows News and Interests or Microsoft Edge Home Screen using python

Tags: python, windows

I wanted to track what news and interests I am shown by the Microsoft news and interests button. To elaborate more, here is the list of interactions I intend to do with the news and interests:

1. browse through all the articles it is showing me and store the heading of the article along with a link to the article.
2. I would also like to click on those article headings to open the entire article and then read the text data present in the opened article.
3. I would also like to click various buttons on the news and interest tab like the *refresh* *more stories like this*, *few stories like this* and *Hide Story* buttons.

It will also be okay if I can use Microsoft edge's home screen, as that also shows articles based on personal interests given that I can interact with them the way I mentioned above.

I have tried pywinauto, but I think doing this with pywinauto auto is lengthy. I was wondering if there is a better way to do the same using some other library or approach.

I would be happy to explain any other details.

Comment: Try using selenium with python for web interaction. Also read [mcve] and edit your post wiht some code examples and real trial and errors.

Comment: Sure, I did see selenium, but since I didn't understand windows GUI automation, I wasn't too sure what I should use. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'll go through the links you have provided and add things to my question that can help others in the future

Answer (score 2):

Try using [clicknium](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium),provides methods to automate various types of applications , such as Web browser , Windows Desktop application , Java application and Sap windows GUI app, etc .
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Sure I'll try that